# Safari web inspector doesn't show redirects

Tags: ios, macos, redirect, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I'm trying to debug web traffic via safari web inspector on mac book (OS X yosemite 10.10.2, safari version 8.0.2), however I can't see request-response traffic for redirects (HTTP response code 301, 302, or javascript redirects).

Lets say page A redirects to B, which redirects to C. In inspector I can see request to page A with response data of site C, but I can't see what happened in the middle (which is very important for me).

In chrome I can see all the redirects as I should, however I can't use chrome, because I want to debug iphone simulator.

Is there a possibility to configure safari inspector to show redirects ?

Answer (score 12):

Currently, you cannot view redirects in Safari's Web Inspector utility. #SuperSad

Comment: This make debugging redirects near impossible :(

Comment: Since this is a regression, I opened a ticket on the Webkit bugtracker: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150005

Comment: Amazing what regression in browser development

Comment: @Tomas Bartalos: alternative option could be to use proxy tool like Charles to view all the http redirect requests.. but if you have https calls then only limited content will be visible

Comment: Correct, it's not supported. We plan to add support.

Comment: @BrianBurg how do I debug Safari then? (which is the new IE, meaning the browser that never works on the first try)